# Posting to Spring controller from view using jQuery $.post() doesn't redirect view

Tags: jquery, spring, post

I am posting to a controller on my site from another page. Here is my $.post():

```
$.post({
    url: '/process',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        operation: MyObject.operation(),
        sessionId: response.session.id,
        orderId: $('#order-id').val(),
        orderAmount: $('#order-amount').val(),
        orderDescription: $('#order-description').val(),
        redirectUrl: MyObject.redirectUrl()
    }
});
```

I'm able to submit the info to my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/process")
public ModelAndView process(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    //...
    // Do something with the request params
    //...

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("response");
    mav.addObject("status", "SUCCESS!");
    return mav;
}
```

I'm able to access the request params, but the controller never redirects to the view. Why is this? Why doesn't returning the mav object redirect the view?

Comment: Instead of `redirectUrl:` have you tried `success:MyObject.redirectUrl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err, you're getting it slightly wrong. `$.post` is an AJAX call, and it cannot automatically redirect you to another page because it is designed like this.

Whenever you fire a call using `$.post`, it will get you back the server response (or error), but doesn't apply it on page by itself. You need to register a callback for it, and write your logic there. If you want to redirect to another page, you will have to change the URL of the browser manually.

In your case, it seems that the server is returning some HTML, so you need to set that HTML explicitly in the page, and change the URL manually. To act on the returned response, you can register a callback like this:

```
$.post( ... )
  .done(function(data) {
    // do something with `data` here. It contains the response returned by the server
  });
```

If you want to just redirect to another page, you can try to set `window.location.href` in the `done` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the .post() function is a shorthand ajax function. I would change it to something like the following:

```
$.post('/process', 
    // This is the data:
    {
        operation: MyObject.operation(),
        sessionId: response.session.id,
        orderId: $('#order-id').val(),
        orderAmount: $('#order-amount').val(),
        orderDescription: $('#order-description').val()
    },
    //callback success function
    MyObject.redirectUrl()
);
```

Alternatively you can likely change the .post to .ajax

```
$.post({
    url: '/process',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        operation: MyObject.operation(),
        sessionId: response.session.id,
        orderId: $('#order-id').val(),
        orderAmount: $('#order-amount').val(),
        orderDescription: $('#order-description').val(),
        // just change to success instead of redirectUrl
        success: MyObject.redirectUrl()
    }
});
```